# Communication between two viewmodels

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, winforms, mvvm

I'm newbie in `MVVM` design pattern, and I have these viewmodels :

**ClassAViewModel**

```
public class ClassAViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private int _nbre = 0;

        public int Nbre
        {
            get
            {
                return _nbre;
            }
            set
            {
                _nbre = value;
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Nbre"));
            }
        }

        #region Events
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        #endregion

    }
```

And **ClassBViewModel**

```
 PUBLIC class ClassBViewModel: INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private Boolean _IsBiggerthanFive = false;

        public bool IsBiggerthanFive
        {
            get
            {
                return _IsBiggerthanFive;
            }
            set
            {
                _IsBiggerthanFive = value;
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("IsBiggerthanFive"));
            }
        }

        #region Events
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        #endregion

    }
```

I need to know if a mecanism of notification between two viewmodels exists , ie in my case if `_nbre > 5` in the first viewmodel, the second viewmodel will be notified and the value of `_IsBiggerthanFive` will be changed. So:

1. How can two viewmodels communicate between them without instanciate one in the other ?
2. What is the best way to accomplish this task?

Comment: The most straightforward approach would probably be to create a ViewModel that contains the instance of each one, and then wire up events to pass data between them.

Comment: The proper design pattern for this is a Mediator.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mediator_pattern

Comment: Another approach is to use Prism and it's EventAggregator class.  Then ViewModel A can raise a Event and ViewModel B can subscribe to the Event and not know/care who raised the event.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree with other commenters that the mediator/pub-sub/event aggregator/messenger is a good way to go.  If you're not using an MVVM framework with a built-in solution, then I recommend [this simple approach that takes advantage of the Reactive extensions](http://joseoncode.com/2010/04/29/event-aggregator-with-reactive-extensions/):

```
public class EventPublisher : IEventPublisher
{
    private readonly ConcurrentDictionary<Type, object> subjects
        = new ConcurrentDictionary<Type, object>();

    public IObservable<TEvent> GetEvent<TEvent>()
    {
        var subject =
            (ISubject<TEvent>) subjects.GetOrAdd(typeof (TEvent),
                        t => new Subject<TEvent>());
        return subject.AsObservable();
    }

    public void Publish<TEvent>(TEvent sampleEvent)
    {
        object subject;
        if (subjects.TryGetValue(typeof(TEvent), out subject))
        {
            ((ISubject<TEvent>)subject)
                .OnNext(sampleEvent);
        }
    }
}
```

That's your whole event aggregator.  Pass an instance of it into each view model, and store it as a reference.  Then create a class to store your event details, let's say "ValueChangedEvent":

```
public class ValueChangedEvent
{
    public int Value
    {
        get { return _value; }
    }
    private readonly int _value;

    public ValueChangedEvent(int value)
    {
        _value = value;
    }
}
```

Publish like this from the first view model:

```
set
{
    _nbre = value;
    PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Nbre"));
    _eventPublisher.Publish(new ValueChangedEvent(value));
}
```

Subscribe in the other class using `GetEvent`:

```
public class ClassBViewModel: INotifyPropertyChanged, IDisposable
{
    private readonly IDisposable _subscriber;

    public ClassBViewModel(IEventPublisher eventPublisher)
    {
        _subscriber = eventPublisher.Subscribe<ValueChangedEvent>(next => 
        {
            IsBiggerthanFive = next.Value > 5;
        });
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _subscriber.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A messenger service is a solution. MVVM Light Toolkit has an implementation of this. What you can do with it, is listen to a specific type of message in your viewmodel and handle it through the messenger. http://www.mvvmlight.net/