# Binding data from different xaml (vector drawing)

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I have an xaml file with a drawn area. In this case, it is a rectangle.

```
<Grid Background="White">
     <Path x:Name="str1" Data="M60,80 L239.5,79.5 239.5,199.5 59.5,199.5 z" Fill="#FFAEAEB4" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="150" Margin="4,0,0,0" Stretch="Fill" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="291"/>
</Grid>
```

.cs

```
 public partial class Page1 : Page
        {
            public Page1()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
            }
        }
```

In the second xaml file I have a form with TextBox

```
<TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="200" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" TextAlignment="Right"/>
```

.cs

```
 public partial class Geometry_1 : Page
{
    public Geometry_1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

}
```

How to bind data to be automatically bound? The rectangle's dimensions are to change dynamically after entering data into the field.

These are two different xaml files.

I create a vector drawing which will change its size depending on the given data in the form

Comment: Implement the MVVM pattern and then use the text changed property of the text box and then update the rectangle accordingly through the view model instance bound to the xaml that contains the rectangle.

Answer (score 0):

You should use data binding:

```
 <Grid Background="White">
      <Path x:Name="str1" 
       Data="M60,80 L239.5,79.5 239.5,199.5 59.5,199.5 z" 
       Fill="#FFAEAEB4" 
       HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
       Height="{Binding ElementName=YSizeTextBox, Path=Text}"
       Margin="4,0,0,0" 
       Stretch="Fill"  
       Stroke="Black"  
       VerticalAlignment="Top" 
       Width={Binding ElementName=XSizeTextBox, Path=Text}"/>

 </Grid>
```

then:

```
 <TextBox x:Name="XSizeTextBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="200" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" TextAlignment="Right"/>
```

If you want to set them from one field you should use [IValueConverter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter(v=vs.95).aspx)

Comment: It works when everything is in the XAML file. Here is another situation

Comment: @programmerJavaPL why do you need 2 `Page`s?

Comment: @XAMlMAX Loaded to various xml files to one of the original elements

Comment: if so, id like you to recommend to use mvvm pattern, as Raviraj Palvankar in a comment to your question, but use separated ViewModels for Page1 and Page2, and communicate between ViewModels. Here is simple solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27452098/communication-between-two-viewmodels